# Laravel Mix TailwindCSS is not loading font files properly

Tags: css, laravel-8, tailwind-css

Laravel Mix TailwindCSS some local fonts not rendering, and classes missing from compiled CSS.

I have followed the tutorial on adding local font files into TailwindCSS, and one font works but the others don't,

The code in the main CSS file `app.css`

```
/* Importing the fonts from the public/fonts directory, using @layer to add them */
@font-face {
    font-family: "JetBrainsMono-Regular";
    src: url(../fonts/JetBrainsMono-Regular.woff2) format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "JetBrainsMono-Medium";
    src: url(.../fonts/JetBrainsMono-Medium.woff2) format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "JetBrainsMono-MediumItalic";
    src: url(.../fonts/JetBrainsMono-MediumItalic.woff2) format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "JetBrainsMono-Bold";
    src: url(.../fonts/JetBrainsMono-Bold.woff2) format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "JetBrainsMono-Italic";
    src: url(.../fonts/JetBrainsMono-Italic.woff2) format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "JetBrainsMono-BoldItalic";
    src: url(.../fonts/JetBrainsMono-BoldItalic.woff2) format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "JetBrainsMono-ExtraBold";
    src: url(.../fonts/JetBrainsMono-ExtraBold.woff2) format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "JetBrainsMono-ExtraBold-Italic";
    src: url(.../fonts/JetBrainsMono-ExtraBold-Italic.woff2) format("woff2");
}

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Here's the code in `tailwind.config.js`

```
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php",
        "./storage/framework/views/*.php",
        "./resources/views/**/*.blade.php",
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                mono: ["JetBrainsMono-Regular", "monospace"],
                medium: ["JetBrainsMono-Medium", "monospace"],
                bold: ["JetBrainsMono-Bold", "monospace"],
                italic: ["JetBrainsMono-Italic", "monospace"],
                boldItalic: ["JetBrainsMono-BoldItalic", "monospace"],
                extraBold: ["JetBrainsMono-ExtraBold", "monospace"],
                extraBoldItalic: ["JetBrainsMono-ExtraBoldItalic", "monospace"],
                mediumBold: ["JetBrainsMono-MediumItalic", "monospace"],
            },
        },
    },

    plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
};
```

Now the resultant compiled `app.css` only has the classes for fonts

```
.font-bold {
    font-family: JetBrainsMono-Bold, monospace;
}
.font-medium {
    font-family: JetBrainsMono-Medium, monospace;
}
.font-mono {
    font-family: JetBrainsMono-Regular, monospace;
}
```

But the only font working is the Regular font, the serif class exists but i didn't modify it so it is not changed, but interestingly the other classes are missing altogether. I have the original font files in the `resources/fonts` folder, an webpack mix is copying them to the `public/fonts` directory, which are also loading in the compiled `app.css`.

A little help would be nice, also using laravel v8.x due to project requirements.